# UDP[number] in wireshark meaning

Tags: udp, wireshark

in wire shark data filter option when we add UDP[50] , so what is this 50 , is it index? i have hex value 93 at UDP[50]. in attached screenshot value 93 is at udp[50] but where is the starting point of this index like where is udp[0].
I want to know the start index of data under wire shark packets. what is this UDP[this number]??

[image: udp]

Comment: UDP[0] is the first byte of UDP **payload**, or the one immediately following the UDP header.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The udp[x] starts at the beginning of the transport layer (e.g. UDP) and starts from zero.  The UDP header is 8 bytes so you'll need to take these 8 bytes into consideration when filtering the payload.

A few examples:

```
udp[0-1] == 0035 # Match bytes 0 to 1 (UDP source port)
udp[0:2] == 0035 # Match 2 bytes starting from 0 (same as above)

udp[8-10] == 5600:22 # Match bytes 8 to 10 (First 3 bytes of UDP payload)
udp[8:3] == 5600:22 # Matches 3 bytes starting from 8 (same as above)
```

If your payload is decoded as data, you can also use data.data[x] so you don't have to offset your filter by 8.  Be careful,though, as it will not match if Wireshark decodes the UDP payload as some other protocol.

Comment: So basically in the picture, data or payload is starting from 01(the highlighted section) , but for UDP[index] i have to start from previous 8 bytes, which in my case is value 06 at UDP[0].